# Storage path set using .env in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpdotenv

I want to configure the storage path in a Laravel 5.1 using the `.env` file. My `bootstrap/app.php` looks like this:

```
<?php
$app = new \Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);
$app->useStoragePath(getenv('STORAGE_PATH'));
```

and the relevant line in .env file is:

```
STORAGE_PATH=/var/www/storage
```

This doesn't work. I figured out the Dotenv library is initialised *after* the bootstrap is processed so the `.env` variables are not available in `bootstrap.php`.

Is there a different place where I can set the storage path and the `.env` variables are available?

Comment: Perhaps this will be of help: https://mattstauffer.co/blog/extending-laravels-application - you could just swap out the path for `env(...)`. Haven't tested it though, so not sure if `env` is ready at that point.

Answer (score 3):

In `config/filesystems.php` you can set your storage path. Try setting your storage path there and see if it works. Note that the example below is my suggestion as to how your `config/filesystems.php` should look. Don't mind the s3 setup. That's a part of my project.

Remember to remove `$app->useStoragePath(getenv('STORAGE_PATH'));` from `app.php`

```
return [

    'default' => 's3',

    'cloud' => 's3',

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => env('STORAGE_PATH'),
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key'    => env('AWS_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
            'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        ],

        'rackspace' => [
            'driver'    => 'rackspace',
            'username'  => 'your-username',
            'key'       => 'your-key',
            'container' => 'your-container',
            'endpoint'  => 'https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/',
            'region'    => 'IAD',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: This doesn't change the storage path for stuff like session/cache/etc. data though, I don't think?

Comment: @ceejayoz Yup, you're right about that. The setup above only sets where file uploads are stored, such as .jpg and .mp4.  You can set session storage path in `config/session.php`.

Comment: and cache in `config/cache.php` etc. :)